# Using jquery for parsing causes image network traffic in Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, html-parsing

I'm writing an extension that scrapes web pages using jquery.  After a while I start getting net errors saying resources not available and errors in the console loading images in the pages I'm scraping.  I thought it might be `$.get()` loading it as html somehow, but it still happens when I use a raw XMLHttpRequest and it appears even when I call `$(text)` with static text.

Looking in the application tab of my background page I can see that there are images, even though they don't exist in the html.  For example run this in the console of any extension background page:

```
$('<div>Hello, world!<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fdc806d0a8834e57b2d9309849dea8cd"/></div>')
```

And you can see the image was loaded on the Application tab in dev tools, though it isn't in the html of the page when inspected and but it's visible on the network tab:

[image: showing image]

I assume that jquery is creating dom elements to use the browser's capabilities for finding elements, and that chrome is happily pre-fetching that image even though the element isn't on the page and the page will never be visible anyway, but it is causing me errors besides the extra network traffic.

I've tried disabling 'precache' in `chrome://flags` but that didn't work.  For now I'm replacing `<img` with `<noimg` which seems to work but is not ideal:

```
$(text.replace(/<img /g, '<noimg '))
```

Is there a way to keep this from happening?  Is there another library besides jQuery (like cheerio in node) that wouldn't actually create dom objects?

Comment: Why you using jQuery with static html text? Because the main purpose of such use is to create a dom elements.

Comment: @Deliaz am loading html using ajax and parsing the html to find data from the web page.  jQuery is easy to use for that, another library would be fine.  I've used `cheerio` in node, but don't know how to make it work in the browser.

Comment: Ok, now I see. You can dig into modules that `cheerio` depends on.  Or still use that replace-way. But in this case I suggest to replace `src` to `data-src`, that allows to keep valid html.

Comment: Use the built-in DOMParser to parse the HTML into a detached document, then use jQuery on that document.

Comment: @wOxxOm nice solution. I checked it, and it doesn't load an image but has full DOM API. Could you please move your comment to answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the built-in [DOMParser](http://devdocs.io/dom/domparser) to parse the HTML into a detached document, then use jQuery on that `document` object:

```js
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(yourHTMLstring, 'text/html');
$('.some.selector', doc).attr('foo', 'bar');
```

In case there may be relative links in the HTML, add a `base` element explicitly:

```js
$(doc.head).append('<base href="' + realFullURL + '">')
```